# CSS navigation bar centralised with no gap between buttons

Tags: html, css

Good evening,

I would like to have a navigation bar which is centralised to the screen without gaps between the button. I realised the gaps can be closed by having a 'float:left'. however, this would result in the navigation bar being flushed to the left. without 'float:left', there will be gaps yet centralised. would appreciate if someone could help me out. thank you!

my css codes are as follow:

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

#nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #086ba9;
    float: left
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}
```

following is my partial html code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Crawler</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Visual Analytics</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Cheers,
ZH

Comment: I recommend you didn't use hard tabs in your code, instead use soft tabs (N spaces instead of 1 tab). It will be more readable across multiple platforms (most platforms support mono-spaced fonts, while not all platforms support visible tabs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/vU4C8/1/

**Changes to be done in CSS:**

```
#nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 display:inline-block; /* Add This*/
}
```

**Note:** `display:inline-block` is added so that `ul` will only take width according to its li's unlike other block elements which take 100% width.

Comment: Your answer is not very useful. Say jsfiddle goes down tomorrow, your answer is practically useless. Please spend some time placing the code in the answer body, explaining on it a bit, then provide a link to the live example :)

Comment: @SVS Thank you for the answer. may I know what does the line 'display: inline-block;" does? Also, why must this line be included in #nav ul instead of #nav or #nav li? thank you so much!

Comment: Actually i changed the code little bit just check the updated answer.
There is no use of margin:0 auto. As u have already applied text-align :center to #nav, which is making ul center aligned & display:inline-block is added because ul will take only the width according to with of all li's

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this approach is "healthy" or not but it did the trick for me

```
#nav ul a{margin:0 -2px;}
```