# Gloss effect navigation menu with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am looking how to make a horizontal navigation menu with HTML and CSS.  I have made use of the good example [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313663/css-navigation-bar-centralised-with-no-gap-between-buttons).

In additional to this, I want to style the menu with a gloss effect, using linear-gradient.  I would like the menus to be one gloss effect as standard, and then change to a second gloss effect for hover.

When I add the linear-gradient effect to the hover, it works as desired.  But when I add the linear-gradient effect for the standard menu, the results are distorted.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Crawler</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Visual Analytics</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS code is as follows:

```
#nav {
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav li {
    margin:0px;
    display:inline;
}
#nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    /*background-color: #086ba9;*/
    float:left
    background-image: linear-gradient(#484848 0%, #484848 50%, #383838 50%, #383838 100%);
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    /*background-color: #35af3b;*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(#33adff 0%, #33adff 50%, #0099ff 50%, #0099ff 100%);
}
```

I hope someone will be able to help.

(I have /*commented out*/ two of the existing background-colors as I want the linear-gradient colors to replace them).

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by standard menu?

Comment: For when the link in my navigation menu isn't being hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed semicolon (;) after float: left in #nav li a